# Alternate way to serialize data using Resource Manager

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, embedded-resource, .net-core-3.0

I have an custom control which inherited from component and one of the property of  my custom control is MemoryStream type.I have stored some layout state information in the LayoutStream property using MemoryStream which is generated in resource file. But In NetCore 3.0 MemoryStream is not supported to serialize the data which stored in resource file.Please refer this link for this issue ("https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7b16d0c7-4d31-4455-876b-1c757d75882c/not-able-to-serialize-memorystream-in-net-core-3?forum=winforms".

Exception Occurs in NetCore 3.0

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
Type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' in Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is not marked as serializable.
```

Please suggestion any alternate solution to serialize the data which stored in resource file

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));

customcontrol  = new MyControl(this.components);
this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.customcontrol )).BeginInit();
this.SuspendLayout();
// 
// customcontrol  
// 


this.customcontrol.LayoutStream = ((System.IO.MemoryStream)(resources.GetObject("customcontrol  .LayoutStream")));
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have already look in that source which you shared. In that source it is marked as Serializable.  But in latest update, MS had removed Serializable attribute in MemoryStream class. So we cannot serialize and de-serialize  the data using MemoryStream. You can able to reproduce the issue in VS2019 16.3 version.

I just need an solution to  serialize and de-serialize  the data(stored in resx file) instead of using MemoryStream.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: any update on this?